# C# query issues returning random values

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I have a small problem. I have a query that needs to return exact text value of the field but when I run it returns random value from dataset which doesn't match. Maybe there is obvious mistake that I just don't see.

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT GlavnaK.Datum, GlavnaK.DatumK, GlavnaK.Valuta, LEFT(GlavnaK.Konto, 3) AS Konto3, GlavnaK.PStanje, GlavnaK.Duguje, GlavnaK.Potrazuje, Kontni.NazivK FROM GlavnaK, Kontni WHERE Konto=Kontni.IDKonta";                
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "GK_arh");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code looks fine, except for the unusual JOIN-via-WHERE (more common would be `FROM GlavnaK, INNER JOIN Kontni ON GlavnaK.Konto=Kontni.IDKonta`) and the missing filter in the WHERE clause (you really want to return *all* records?). I'm afraid we'll need to see a [mcve] (including the SQL statements to create the table and fill the database) to help you.

Comment: You never get random data from a database.  Some databases like SQL server the order is random and need to sort to get same results every time.  You are using access where data is always returned in same order. The best way of debugging you issue is to open the database with access and compare what is in the database with the results in c#.  You can also run the query in access to see if you get same results. Often cases like this you have two copies of the access database and the connection string is connect to the wrong database.  Also make sure you do not have blank rows in the access file.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean is that the return value is random, you can try add Sort.

```
SELECT GlavnaK.Datum, GlavnaK.DatumK, GlavnaK.Valuta, LEFT(GlavnaK.Konto, 3) AS Konto3, GlavnaK.PStanje, GlavnaK.Duguje, GlavnaK.Potrazuje, Kontni.NazivK
FROM GlavnaK, Kontni
WHERE Konto=Kontni.IDKonta
ORDER BY GlavnaK.Datum
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjust to hold a correct syntax for INNER JOIN:

```cs
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT GlavnaK.Datum, GlavnaK.DatumK, GlavnaK.Valuta, LEFT(GlavnaK.Konto, 3) AS Konto3, " +
    "GlavnaK.PStanje, GlavnaK.Duguje, GlavnaK.Potrazuje, Kontni.NazivK " +
    "FROM GlavnaK " +
    "INNER JOIN Kontni " + 
    "ON Glavnak.Konto = Kontni.IDKonta";
```